# How to process negative rational exponents

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I have been doing questions for Precalculus fundamentals that include rational exponents, but they have all been positive up til this point, and I am a bit confused how to process them when they are negative.  Do we just flip everything like with a normal negative exponent?

For example what I have been doing

$(4b)^{1/2}(8b)^{1/4} = 32b^{2/6}$

I have more examples if you wish I can post more.

But basically now I have a question that does this:

$(8y^3)^{-2/3}$ and I am supposed to simplify.

Another one $(u^4v^6)^{-1/3}$

I don't know how to make fractions and exponents to type these more properly/legibly.

Answer (score 1):

Long story short: yes, with negative fractional exponents, everything is just "business as usual": all the rules you've learned apply equally well to **all** exponents, whether positive or negative, whole number or fraction.

For example, $b^mb^n = b^{n+m}$ whatever numbers $n$ and $m$ happen to be. (Be careful: this rule only applies if you're raising the same number to different powers; this rule doesn't apply to your first example, assuming I understand what you meant to write)

Similarly, $(b^n)^m = b^{nm}$, whatever kinds of numbers $n$ and $m$ are.

When we're talking about negative exponents, they are still defined as usual:

$$
b^{-n} = \frac{1}{b^n}.
$$ 
Similarly, fractional exponents are defined as usual:
$$
b^{m/n} = \sqrt[n]{b^m}.
$$
For example, we can compute $b^{-2/3} = \frac{1}{b^{2/3}} = \frac{1}{\sqrt[3]{b^2}}$.

I hope this helps!

Comment: Thank you your response helped!

Comment: I'm very glad to hear it, I hope math.SE can help with any future math questions you encounter! If you're interested, take the [tour](http://math.stackexchange.com/tour) to learn more about the website.

Comment: That will be great, I knew there would be a better way to format my question but I was trying to review/answer it before class today.  I will definitely take the tour and read how to use this site effectively before my next questions :D

Answer (score 0):

I'm having trouble reading the questions, so I'll do a few examples:

$(x^3)^{-2}=x^{-6}=\frac{1}{x^6}$

$(\frac{3}{2})^{-\frac{2}{5}}=1\div(\frac{3}{2})^\frac{2}{5}=(\frac{2}{3})^\frac{2}{5}$

$2^{-\frac{1}{2}}=1\div 2^\frac{1}{2}=\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}$

Comment: I'm glad! Sorry I was unable to address your question directly - parsing is hard when it's not in LaTeX

Answer (score 0):

Your first example should be $2^{7/4}b^{3/4}$, as $1/2 + 1/4 = 3/4$, $4^{1/2} = 2$, and $8^{1/4} = 2^{3/4}$.
When taking exponents of exponents you distribute to the terms multiply the exponents:

$(x^a)^b = x^{ab} $

$x^{-a} = \frac{1}{x^a}$

So for your problems

$(8y^3)^{-2/3} = 8^{-2/3}y^{-2} = \frac{1}{4y^2} $

$(u^4v^6)^{-1/3} = u^{-4/3}v^{-2} $

Use MathJaX to make the expressions more legible. This website has some good guides.

Comment: That's not true; if $b=1$ neither your nor the original version of the first equation is true. That's why I left the non-LaTeX there, because I had a feeling something has been lost in translation.

Comment: Thank you for catching my mistake as I did make edit: several, but these are equations and hold true even if $b = 1$.

Comment: Thank you your response helped!